# How to modify browser in markdown mode?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I use emacs and markdown-mode to write markdown file.
When I press `C-c C-c p` to call a browser to preview my markdown file, it runs the following code.

```
(defun markdown-preview (&optional output-buffer-name)
  "Run `markdown-command' on the current buffer and view output in browser.
When OUTPUT-BUFFER-NAME is given, insert the output in the buffer with
that name."
  (interactive)
  (browse-url-of-buffer (markdown-standalone markdown-output-buffer-name)))
```

It will call my default system browser Firefox. But I want to call Chrome to preview my markdown file, and I don't want to modify my default system browser.
How to modify the code to call Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up [advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) to temporarily override the value of `browse-url-browser-function` when `markdown-preview` is invoked.

```
(defadvice markdown-preview (around markdown-preview-in-chromium activate compile)
   (let ((browse-url-browser-function #'browse-url-chromium))                    
     ad-do-it))
```

As noted by @jpkotta in the comments, you can configure Emacs to use Chrome instead of Chromium with `(setq browse-url-chromium-program "google-chrome")` (or whatever your chrome binary is named).

Comment: With the new advice syntax (I think it was added in 24.4, `defadvice` is implemented with nadvice library now): `(advice-add 'markdown-preview :around (lambda (orig &rest args) "Use chromium as default browser" (let ((browse-url-browser-function #'browse-url-chromium)) (apply orig args))))`

Comment: You can use chrome with `(setq browse-url-chromium-program "google-chrome")` (or whatever your chrome binary is named).